# CL programming: CPF9841 : Override not found at specified level error

Tags: ibm-midrange

Have come across a situation where a CLLE program throws the below error on random occasions:

```
Message text for CPF9841 is: Override not found at      
  specified level.
```

The line throwing the error is `DLTOVR  FILE(QSYSPRT)`.

The suspicion is that multiple submissions of the same command are resulting in this error.

A bit of googling around suggests that defining a call level as *JOB might be helpful to get rid of this error.

Any better suggestions?

So if the DLTOVR command is done at *JOB level, then the OVRPRTF command would also be required to be done at the *JOB level I believe?

Comment: Posting the code would be helpful.  Also, a description of the activation groups that are in use.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the CLLE is issuing an exception message, then after the DLTOVR, put a MONMSG CPF9841 and trap the error.  If the code is really randomly (how?) issuing too many DLTOVR commands, the code probably wants to just ignore and continue.

If the problem is that the OVRPRTF is not honoured by the HLL program, then you need to make sure that 
a) the activation group attributes match
b) change the override scope to something else, like *JOB